# How to turn off iedit-mode quickly after finishing an edit?

Tags: multiple-cursors

I like how multiple-cursors is turned off when pressing <kbd>RET</kbd>, and this is not the case for iedit-mode, how can I emulate that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From future. Now it is

```
(define-key iedit-mode-occurrence-keymap (kbd "RET") 'iedit-mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a key for the iedit-mode keyboard map, like this:

```
(define-key iedit-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'iedit-mode)
```

So, when you start editing a piece of text with iedit-mode, you can turn it off by just pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> or any key you like.